PBI: Is there a way to filter visual but not data?
using PBI for a Report and wondering if it's possible to have a filter on a visual, that does not apply to data behind:
I have observations within a flow that might have *"flow_start_date" at t-10*,
I created a matrix view showing volumes based on *"flow_start_date" t, t-1,t-2*.
Since some observations having "flow_start_date" < t-2 might still be in the flow, I would like to have them counted in the matrix, but don't want the matrix visual to go all way back to t-10.
Any help on this?

You can choose which visual is impacted by your filter.
In the format menu, click on "modify interactions"

Then you click on your slicer, and deactivate the visuals you do not want impacted by your selection :

I hope this helps.
